# add email sending host to SPF record with redirect

Tags: spf

Let us say our domain name is: somedomain.com

We are using a hosted microsoft exchange server for our domain and our current SPF record looks like this

the TXT record for somedomain.com currently has:

v=spf1 redirect=exchange.someisp.net.au

Now, we also want to send emails using sendmail on a linux box whose host name is skynet.somedomain.com and has ip address 1.2.3.4

How do we modify the TXT record to add this host name, yet still keep exchange.someisp.net.au?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Then I think your SPF record should look like this:

```
v=spf1 a:skynet.somedomain.com redirect=exchange.someisp.net.au
```

The redirect modifier will only be checked if all mechanisms (a, mx, ip, etc) don't match. So if the a mechanism match the rule will return PASS else it will test the redirect as today.